How to block all internet traffic to system and allow only connection from particular IP address
I am using a windows 10 laptop, and openvpn server and proxy server in remote location(cloud), i want to block all internet connection to my system and only allow connection from and to openvpn server using windows firewall. If anyone has answers are approch please let me know.
I tried multiple ways adding firewall rules to block and allow the ip address, but internet is completely block, after block rule is applied, cant reach the openvpn server.
